# Return server-side calculation to client without using a collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

Data is on the client generated and saved in a local collection:

```
ListLocal = new Mongo.Collection(null);

let seed = [{
        name: "A",
        value: 1
    }, {
        name: "B",
        value: 2
    }, {
        name: "C",
        value: 3
    }];

    if (ListLocal.find().count() === 0) {
        ListLocal.forEach(function(entry) {
            ListLocal.insert(entry);
        });
    };
```

Then it is passed on the client to the server for further processing:

```
Template.home.events({
    "click .btn-process": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let localData = ListLocal.find({}).fetch();

        Meteor.call("processData", localData);
    }
});
```

The server accepts the data and passes it to a server-side Method that does some stuff with it, eg. doubles all values of the passed Objects:

```
Meteor.methods({
    processData(localData) {
        calculateDouble(localData);
    }
});

calculateDouble(localData) {
    // ...
    return calculatedData;
}
```

Now i want to display this calculatedData client-side without saving it in a server-side database.

**Question:** How can i pass this data to the client?

Comment: Why not just `return` it from your method? Is `calculateDouble` sync or async?

Comment: Basic values come from the database and are saved in the local collection. there each user can modify these values on his own terms. 
For further evalutation the values are passed to the server, recalculated and than they should be passed back to the client to be displayed. 
So my question is: how can i use the return value in a template helper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return the data from the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    "processData": function(localData) {
        return calculateDouble(localData);
    }
});

calculateDouble(localData) {
    // ...
    return calculatedData;
}
```

To call the method in the event:

```
Template.home.events({
    "click .btn-process": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let localData = ListLocal.find({}).fetch();

        Meteor.call("processData", localData, function(error, result){
           //handle what you need to do with the result here.
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - my question is: how do i access this Method from the Template helper? Since i have no database to publish the methods' return value from.

Comment: You can just put it into a `Session` variable on the client, or a reactive var, or a global even.

Comment: That works! Thanks! I just added the error parameter to your callback function, otherwise it just returns "undefined".
@MichelFloyd - how do mean to use a Session variable? Without using Meteor.call?

Comment: `Meteor.call("processData",localData,function(result){Session.set("myVar",result)});`